# Why does this CLI app that I've written with the Click library not working properly?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, click, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I've created this CLI application to initialize db and etc. I've even created an app context for db, but I got an error.

Please note that I'm using `docker` and `docker-compose`. I know that this error is related to the time when we have several applications and the database does not know which application to work with. But I don't know how to solve the problem.

```
    from click import group, command, option, pass_context

    from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

    from call.app import create_app
    from call.extensions import db
    from call.blueprints.user.models import User

    # Create an app context for the database connection.
    app = create_app()
    db.init_app(app)


    @group()
    def cli():
        """ Run SQLite3 related tasks. """
        pass


    @command()
    @option('--with-testdb/--no-with-testdb', default=False,
                  help='Create a test db too?')
    def init(with_testdb):
        """
        Initialize the database.

        :param with_testdb: Create a test database
        :return: None
        """
        with app.app_context():
            db.drop_all()
            db.create_all()

            if with_testdb:
                db_uri = '{0}_test'.format(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])

                if not database_exists(db_uri):
                    create_database(db_uri)

        return None


    @command()
    def seed():
        """
        Seed the database with an initial user.

        :return: User instance
        """
        with app.app_context():
            if User.find_by_identity(app.config['SEED_ADMIN_EMAIL']) is not None:
                return None

            params = {
                'role': 'admin',
                'email': app.config['SEED_ADMIN_EMAIL'],
                'password': app.config['SEED_ADMIN_PASSWORD']
            }

        return User(**params).save()


    @command()
    @option('--with-testdb/--no-with-testdb', default=False,
                  help='Create a test db too?')
    @pass_context
    def reset(ctx, with_testdb):
        """
        Init and seed automatically.

        :param with_testdb: Create a test database
        :return: None
        """
        with app.app_context():
            print(ctx)
            ctx.invoke(init, with_testdb=with_testdb)
            ctx.invoke(seed)

        return None


    cli.add_command(init)
    cli.add_command(seed)
    cli.add_command(reset)
```

Here is the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:813: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  'Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. '
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:834: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:834: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that the `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']` is not available.

I suggest setting it as an env variable in your docker compose file. taking a look at flask documentation. Example:
docker-compose:

```
web:
  environment:
    - SECRET_KEY=123
```

App:

```
import os

_mail_enabled = os.environ.get("MAIL_ENABLED", default="true")
MAIL_ENABLED = _mail_enabled.lower() in {"1", "t", "true"}

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")

if not SECRET_KEY:
    raise ValueError("No SECRET_KEY set for Flask application")
```

Comment: Your solution worked. I think it couldn't load the project settings.